# Magento 2.2.2 Advanced Reporting Not working

Tags: magento2.2.2, reports, data

I went through this process https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/reports/advanced-reporting.html

but yet I still get 404.

[image]

Anyone have any idea what else could be?
Thank you.

Comment: if your store does not have multiple base currencies, is SSL-encrypted, and is on a publicly available domain, you can try re-authenticating your Advanced Reporting subscription by disabling and re-enabling the service in your Magento admin panel

Comment: @AdityaShah I have 3 website running under same magento installation.  they are UK,US, EUROPE  each website has its own currency SSL encrypted yes but will the 3 store affect ?

Comment: The initial release of Advanced Reporting supports only one base currency [here](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/reports/advanced-reporting.html)

Comment: @AdityaShah  this I've seen but not sure I understand so If I have multi website setup with another currencies like I do it will not work?  I don;t have multi store or multi store view only one per website

Comment: the magento support forum says..
But ensure that a Magento Analytics user exists

Comment: Open the user, in their API tab make sure it has Analytics->API resource checked

Comment: @AdityaShah Magento Analytics user in Integration is all checked jus to be sure but thing that I am not sure of is the **Callback URL** and the **Identity link URL** what should they be can it be empty?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77481/discussion-between-juliano-vargas-and-aditya-shah).

Comment: For me this issue was finally fixed when I updated from 2.2.3 to 2.2.6, in case it can help..

Comment: @David i have used Magento2.3 EC but facing the same issue. how can you enable the Advance Reporting? can you explain please.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party but I was trying for over 2 months to make Advanced Reporting work even though I had followed every step of the official guide and also couldn't find a proper search result for my problem. My issue was that in my server's file system under the following path tmp/analytics/ huge tar files were being created every time Magento 2 was collecting data for Advanced Reporting (It is the "Time of day to send data" field in its configuration page).

This issue was solved by applying the following patch https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21452#issuecomment-467799311

If this is your problem too, you can check this question and answer for more info https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/245239/66247

(for the record I am using Magento v2.2.7)