# Disk space issue with Advanced Reporting after update from 2.2.3 to 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

I'm experiencing a big weird issue. I have updated 3 days ago from Magento **2.2.3 to 2.2.6**. Everything went just fine. But on the day after the update, I received a warning from server health monitor regarding a disk space issue.
A file had been created on sever root, in /tmp/analytics folder:

**~tmp-1537660818.7487tar.tar : 11G**

3 days after that, I have 3 files in that folder:

**~tmp-1537660818.7487tar.tar : 11G**

**~tmp-1537747210.659tar.tar : 6,5M**

**~tmp-1537833608.7409tar.tar : 2G**

File owner is the website owner. When I open file with terminal, I get endless lines repetitions :

```
x order_addresses.csv
x ../: Path contains '..'
x .././: Path contains '..'
x ../././: Path contains '..'
x .././././: Path contains '..'
x ../././././: Path contains '..'
x .././././././: Path contains '..'
x ../././././././: Path contains '..'
x .././././././././: Path contains '..'
x ../././././././././: Path contains '..'
x .././././././././././: Path contains '..'
x ../././././././././././: Path contains '..'
```

Files seem to be created along with the database backup each night. But I can't find logic between database backup and csv files. I disabled database backup for the coming night to see if the problem remains.

I found 2 files mentionning order_addresses:

**vendor/magento/module-sales-analytics/etc/analytics.xml**

**vendor/magento/module-sales-analytics/etc/reports.xml**

Any idea on what could cause this issue ?

**** **EDIT 1** ****

Disabling the database auto backup did not  change my issue. Tonight a 6.5M file has been created. I will not delete this one as it's not a big problem of disk space and keep on checking this issue.

**** **EDIT 2** ****

Uncompressing the tar files with **tar ztvf yourfile.tar.gz** gives me other results:

```
-rw-rw-r--  0 domainuser psacln 100669 26 sep 02:00 order_addresses.csv
drwxrwxr-x  0 domainuser psacln      0 26 sep 02:00 ../
drwxrwxr-x  0 domainuser psacln      0 26 sep 02:00 .././
drwxrwxr-x  0 domainuser psacln      0 26 sep 02:00 ../././
drwxrwxr-x  0 domainuser psacln      0 26 sep 02:00 .././././
drwxrwxr-x  0 domainuser psacln      0 26 sep 02:00 ../././././
drwxrwxr-x  0 domainuser psacln      0 26 sep 02:00 .././././././
drwxrwxr-x  0 domainuser psacln      0 26 sep 02:00 ../././././././
drwxrwxr-x  0 domainuser psacln      0 26 sep 02:00 .././././././././
```

Last night the server got stuck again with a 13G file.

**** **EDIT 3** ****

I tried to open the file with **7zX**, it loops endlessly. I also tried with an application called **Décompresser (2.0.2)**, and it creates a folder with an error alert. The folder contains a order_addresses.csv file with 5 columns : **entity_id, customer_id, city, region, country_id**.
But I can't find what creates or tries to create, or at least tries to handle that file every night...

Again, only place I can find order_addresses mentionned is in **vendor/magento/module-sales-analytics**... Any idea ?

**** **EDIT 4** ****

**module-sales-analytics** seems to be used by **Advanced Reporting module** which on my side is very buggy from the start! It always leads me to a 404. I will try to reconfigure the module, or disable it.

**** **EDIT 5** ****

Setup / Configuration:

```
Linux dedicated server 
CentOS 6.9 
Plesk Onyx Version 17.5.3 
PHP 7.0.32 
Document root : httpdocs/pub 
Include_path : .:/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library
```

**** **EDIT 6** ****

Reauthorizing Magento Analytics user did not change the thing, still got a 13G file this night. I just disabled **Advanced Reporting module** to see the change.

**** **EDIT 7** ****

Disabling **Advanced Reporting module** solved the issue, but it's not the best solution I think, more of a workaround. I tried to reach **Advanced Reporting module** devs but no answers.

Comment: You must check the extension which have crons and also check the cron execution time interval and number of crons added to server.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes, indeed I think I found which module is causing my troubles, I just added an edit in my question.

Comment: ahh, great.. :)

Comment: You are certainly not the only one ;) Thanks for sharing. Did the code fix also resolve the 404 error or just the disk space topic (never made advanced reporting running - unfortunately)? Thanks!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/141396)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I  checked this issue again, seems like I was not the only one facing this.

Problem seems to be fixed with this commit:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/8e1a5d342cbc63f58529b6c25be41c7d9a979a66

Some code has to be changed:

```
$dirFiles = array_diff($dirFiles, ['..', '.']);
```

instead of

```
array_shift($dirFiles);
/* remove  './'*/
array_shift($dirFiles);
/* remove  '../'*/
```

around line 262 in **lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Archive/Tar.php** or **vendor/magento/framework/Archive/Tar.php** depending on the install.

The fix worked for me.

Comment: Here's more info about it: https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038497891-MBI-Advanced-Reporting-creating-large-files-in-tmp-analytics?flash_digest=19dac8b4ac8ec732d10caf9cf6868159d8509b5e

Comment: Also: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/18322  -- It's been released in magento 2.3.1